# How to set custom class to equal exchange in Apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a custom class I'm trying to set to an incoming exchange message. But i keep getting this error when I try to set it.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.models.CsvModel
```

My route is below

```
private final DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.models.CsvModel.class); 

 @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("{{input.files.csv}}")
            .routeId("CSVConverter")
            .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
            .unmarshal(bindy)
            .split(body().tokenize(","))
            .process(new CsvConverterProcessor())
            .to("{{output.files.csv}}");
  }
```

And my custom class is this

```
@Component
@CsvRecord(separator = " ")
public class CsvModel {
 //some fields with setters, getters, and 2 constructors
//fields are annotated with @Datafield and pos
}
```

I try to set it in my processor process method as so  `CsvModel model = (CsvModel) exchange.getIn().getBody();`

I've seen an example where they do exactly this and it works for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you ever actually converted the exchange body to a CsvModel. To do that, you'll need to call .convertBodyTo() prior to your processor receiving the exchange.

```
.split(body().tokenize(","))
.convertBodyTo(CsvModel.class)
.process(new CsvConverterProcessor())
```

Camel also doesn't know how to convert the exchange body to/from your class, so you'll need to add a custom type converter, either with annotations or by extending the TypeConverter class. Here's a sample skeleton of what you'll need. I would also include a converter to go the other way(CsvModel -> String). You can find full documentation for type converters here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/type-converter.html

```
@Converter(generateBulkLoader = true)
public class CsvModelConverter {

  @Converter
  public static CsvModelConverter toCsvModel(String data, Exchange exchange) {
     CsvModel newModel = //Whatever you need to do to convert the string data to your class
     return csvModel;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the ```unmarshal(bindy)``` line convert the exchange body to a CsvModel?

Comment: Not from what I've read. I'm not really that familiar with how Camel handles marshalling/unmarshalling, but this question covers it in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609946/apache-camel-data-format-vs-type-converter

Comment: Oh, but I guess I should mention that I have implemented type converters in Camel, so that we could use a custom class in the Exchange. After calling convertBodyTo earlier in a route, we're able to get the class in processors with "MyClass tmp = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyClass.class)".